# WinAPI menu freezes after some clicks

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I have an application in win32 that has a top menu in its main window, this menu has 2 options with submenus in each.

The problem is..after some clicks on its options it suddenly freezes. The rest of the application keeps responding normally, but when i click on the menu options, the buttons go down like pressed and the submenus just doesnt appear, and i need to restart the application or it wont work anymore.

I thik it is something related to memory allocation, maybe i need to free some allocation, but since im new to this kind of programming, i can say just looking at it.

Some code..i think its in the window procedure where i manipulate the WM_COMMAND that theres something wrong:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

int wmId, wmEvent;
PAINTSTRUCT ps;
HDC hdc;

HMENU hMenubar = CreateMenu();
HMENU hFile = CreateMenu();
HMENU hEDIT = CreateMenu();
HMENU hHelp = CreateMenu();     



switch (message)
{


case WM_COMMAND:
    wmId    = LOWORD(wParam);
    wmEvent = HIWORD(wParam);

    // Parse the menu selections:

    switch (wmId)
    {
    case ID_FILE_DIALOG2:
        DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG2), hWnd, Add);
        break;

    case ID_FILE_TESTE:

    Check();

    break;

    case ID_FILE_DIALOG1:
        DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG1), hWnd, Conf);
        break;

    case ID_OPEN:
        Open();
        break;

    case IDM_ABOUT:
        DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
        break;

    case IDM_EXIT:
        DestroyWindow(hWnd);
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);

    }
    break;

case WM_PAINT:

    break;

case WM_CLOSE:
    DestroyWindow(hWnd);
        PostQuitMessage(0);
break;

case WM_DESTROY:

break;

default: 
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);

}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably running out of handles as you're creating the menus each time WndProc is called. This function gets called a lot!

Create the menus once during the app initialisation.

Comment: Thank you very much, i declared it on InitInstance() so it creates the menu just on the application initialization and it solved :).